# How to use tabs widget in magento2

Tags: magento2, jquery, tabs, widget

I am stuck in using tabs widget in Magento2. I have not found any resource that teaches about this. The only resource is this: [DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_tabs.html) But this is useless. It is only a reference of options and methods, but not how to use it.

I have this in attributes.phtml of my custom theme:

```
<div id="Tabs1">
    <ul>
        <?php $count = 0 ?>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <li data-role="title"><a href="#tabs-<?php echo ++$count ?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php $count = 0 ?>
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <div id="tabs-<?php echo ++$count ?>" data-role="content">
            <p><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
], function($){
    $(function () {
        $("#Tabs1").tabs();
    });        
});
</script>
```

**But that does not work. Can you show me where is the error, please?**

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have error on the page because you miss your `tabs` widget in dependencies list (at list if you want to use Magento's `tabs` widget).

Correct:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/tabs'
], function($){
```

But I can suggest more convenient way:

```
<div data-mage-init='{"mage/tabs":{}}'>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_key => $_data): ?>
            <li data-role="title"><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $_key ?>">...
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_key => $_data): ?>
        <div id="tabs-<?php echo $_key ?>" data-role="content">
            ...
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

`mage/tabs.js` will be loaded by Magento's App and initialized on needed element.

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. It does simply nothing. By the way, jquery/ui includes tabs widget as I have checked in jquery-ui.js. But i tested both ways. After page is loaded, the data-mage-init attribute is removed which indicates something is happening, but that is the only behaviour. I tried also what appears in this page: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/c58d2d/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml#L23-L36. But it did not work either. Not even errors are shown in console output.

Comment: The problem was that I have not included default css styles. I included them and it looks pretty now :-)

Comment: How do you include those styles?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me if I remove the second `$(function () {})` wrap like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui'
    ], function($){
        $("#Tabs1").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this url to solve the widget tab.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_tabs.html

for active class css

.nav-tabs li[aria-expanded="true"]{background:#f26c4f !important;}
.nav-tabs li[aria-expanded="true"] a{background:#f26c4f !important;color:#fff !important;}